# Is there a Java library to merge data model?

Tags: java, merge, data-modeling

We want to merge 2 set of data using the same model:
we have 2 databases that have the same DDL, but containing different data.
We want to merge both and save the result. Merge should be configurable to allow us to write some rules.

Do you known any framework / library able to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.

> Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean
>   mapper that recursively copies data
>   from one object to another. Typically,
>   these Java Beans will be of different
>   complex types. Dozer supports simple
>   property mapping, complex type
>   mapping, bi-directional mapping,
>   implicit-explicit mapping, as well as
>   recursive mapping. This includes
>   mapping collection attributes that
>   also need mapping at the element
>   level.

Comment: I was aware of Dozer, but was not sure about using it for this purpose.